# How is the reflection probability calculated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection

I was reading Feynman's book on QED and I stumbled upon the probability of reflection of photons by a piece of glass. Is there a way to calculate the probabilty of reflection?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   This is contained in Maxwell's equation.  The probabilities are obtained from Fresnel's coefficients, and depend on the angle of incidence, as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Normal_incidence).

There is also this [nice set of slides](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec29.pdf) that also gives quite a bit of details on how these are calculated from Maxwell's equations.